# When creating a new object how do I relate it to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model in which allows a user to create many of. I want only the user to see these objects if they are logged in. So as of now I have the object `belongs_to:user` and user `has_many:objects` set, but how do I set the user property when an object is created. I basically want the user to create this and then later on display all of them back using object `find(where user=current_user)`.

Comment: Do you have some kind of authentication system in place?

Comment: I have `Devise` and am considering using `CanCan` as well but don't know what I will get with `CanCan`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your objects_controller.rb create action do this:

```
@object = current_user.objects.build(params[:object])
```

Instead of:

```
@object = Object.new(params[:object])
```

To retrieve the current user's objects, simply:

```
@objects = current_user.objects
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something that will authenticate Users. I would suggest using `Devise` or `authlogic`

Comment: Seeing as the OP has a 'current_user' method, it may be safe to assume

Answer (score 0):

```
@object = current_user.objects.build(params[:object])

<% if current_user %>
<% objects = current_user.objects %>
<% for object in objects %>
   <% object.name %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<p>Not logged in</p>
<% end %>
```